# Logistic Regression - loss function

Tags: machine-learning

[image]

I tried to substitute p = 1/1+e(-z) back to the first function, but I can't reach the simplify function.

For the middle term, I get the sum of (z(1-t^i)) instead of the sum of (t^i z^i). I don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: This is a math question (high school algebra) and does not belong to this site (programming questions). I'm not sure how to move it, though. Can any moderator help fixing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not posted your solution,I cannot say what mistake you did commit but I think you need to substitute p(C=0|x,w) and p(C=1|x,w) both and not just p=1/1+e(-z).Here goes the derivation-

substitute p(C=0|x,w) and p(C=1|x,w) in main equation(first)(sum==summation) and z is z^(i)

L=-sum(t^(i)*log(e^-z))+sum(t^(i)*log(1+e^-z))+sum(log(1+e^-z)-sum(t^(i)*log(1+e^-z))

The second and fourth term cancel out.We get

L=-sum(t^(i)*log(e^-z))+sum(log(1+e^-z)

By prop of logarithms-log(e^(-z))=z.So

L=sum(log(1+e^-z)+sum(t^(i)*z)